# File processing design suggesstion

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel

I am developing an application to process multiple csv files using apache camel. The processing involves multiple transformation and validations.

The format of files can be dynamic but we will always get the csv header before it arrives. 
I don't want to add a new model every time a new format arrives, instead I want to create a Map with key value pairs.
But for simple validations and complex rules, I had to convert it into a bean (since using drools and bean validation).

If I create a lots of models for incoming files, then camel processor has to have lots of conditional statements for choosing a correct strategy to process. probably instanceof (bad idea) or type based strategy selection.

Can someone suggest me a design approach to tackle this.

Comment: Does these files contain the same data? For reading csv files I would recommend using Camel Bindy and the Camel implementation of Dozer for transforming the beans.

Comment: Thanks Tom..Thats what exactly I am doing bindy, dozer, drools and custom bean validation. The files doesn't the same data but has headers. Bindy has a problem, you have to keep your models in separate package and as I said earlier, I want to dynamically accommodate new file just by adding either DB entry or property file entry. I am hesitant to add java models as they can proliferate.Also I am not using camel implementation of dozer, as I feel too much dependency on camel by that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Camel CSV](http://camel.apache.org/csv.html) component where you get a list with maps holding key value pairs:

```
final CsvDataFormat format = new CsvDataFormat();
format.setUseMaps(true);
format.setDelimiter(",");

from("direct:start")
    .unmarshal(format)
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            final List<Map<String, String>> body = exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class);
            // transform and/or validate data...  
     });
```

The processor could transform your data to Java beans or directly validate the content.

Comment: The problem is drools which requires a static and type safe model.

Comment: @VGaur If you need a type safe model, then you must bite the bullet and add a new model each time a new model arrives.